# "-bash: //MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory" when using VS Code using " . code " shortcut

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, terminal, ide

My IDE is VS Code
I have been using it many times
suddenly when I open vs code in my terminal

`. code` or `source code`

it displays error

```
-bash: //MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

[Process completed]

How do I fix this? I just want to get my normal vs code to work functional again just as before

Answer (score 24):

I visited https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editor/setup/

Afterwards, I copy and pasted the following onto a new line in my system ~/.zshrc file

`code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}`

Don't forget to `source ~/.zshrc` after then restart terminal

Worked great, now I can run `code .` again for any folder/project

Answer (score 1):

For me, I didn't have a globally accessible `python`. Which is called in `/usr/local/bin/code`.

Since I'm using `asdf` I simply did `asdf global python x.xx.x`.
If you are not using `asdf` perhaps perform `brew install python`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac

Comment: i have solved it.. I used the code this way
```code .```
instead of 
```. code```
I don't know why it was changed but it is weird.. maybe its from the previous update

Comment: `. code` doesn't make any sense from  the shell point of view. That could never have worked. ALL unix commands that take file paths work like `commandname [filepath]` and `.` is the file path (current directory).

Answer (score 0):

I have already figured it out.

`code .`

instead of

`. code`

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  Solved a massive headache